# Amazon S3 absolute path when adding photos through SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm adding some photos manually from a ruby rake task.

```
photos_insert = conn.query("INSERT INTO photos (photo) VALUES ('myimage.jpg')")
```

It is working fine, but, since I have carrierwave's fog into amazon s3, it will try to find the image as `https://myweb.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/photo/614/thumb_myimage.jpg`

instead of `myimage.jpg` only. Any ideas on how can I make the correct routes when getting images?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the path since you are using carrierwave? Please explain a use case where this is causing issues.

Comment: Since im using carrierwave with amazon s3, every image in the photo model is preceded by
https://myweb.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/photo/614/thumb_, so when I add them manually into the ddbb, when rendering, the route will be wrong, because i don't need that prefix

Comment: I would then store these in a separate column in the model or possibly a separate model all together dependent upon the logic. [read through the source comments on what mounting an uploader actually does](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb)